# Why is this ISO-8601 time conversion not working?

Tags: c#

I'm unclear why the program fails to convert time.  Can anyone help?  I thought HH:MM:SS followed by the Z was valid ISO, but the .net datetime parser reports that it is not in an acceptable format.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace DateTimePractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This string works with the extended info beyond just seconds
            //string dateString = "2008-06-11T16:11:20.0904778Z";
            // This appears to be a valid ISO-8601 time, but the parser fails
            string dateString = "2008-06-11T16:11:20Z";
            string finalResult;
            DateTime result;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out result))
                finalResult = string.Format("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, result, result.Kind);
            else
                finalResult = string.Format("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);
            Console.WriteLine(finalResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Please** read the MSDN documentation, especially about the "o" round-trip format specifier and the format string it represents ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip)). Then, ask yourself the question what the word "**Exact**" stands for in the method name *TryParseExact*...

Comment: @elgonzo Your link doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff, thanks. Link fixed in my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @elgonzo is writing in the comments is correct. A ParseExact with an ISO 8601 is meant to be parsed exactly in the expected format, therefore it will need the corresponding fractional number of seconds. I would say that the part in the linked document where it states this is the following:

> Note that if you call a parsing method with the custom format string that corresponds to the "O" or "o" format specifier, you won't get the same results as "O" or "o". This is because parsing methods that use a custom format string can't parse the string representation of date and time values that lack a time zone component or use "Z" to indicate UTC.

In your case you can just replace TryParseExact with TryParse, and omit the "o" format specifier. It should be able to parse your date regardless of the fractional seconds part.

Comment: Oddly enough, the short version of TryParse automatically converts back to local so I have to use the elongated version of the function to keep it in UTC.  Thanks for the answer.